# Prefix sum variation

Tags: algorithm, computer-science-theory

I'm trying parallelize some software that performs some recursive linear equations. I think some of them might be adapted into prefix sums. A couple of examples of the kinds of equation I'm dealing with are below.

The standard prefix sum is defined as:

```
y[i] = y[i-1] + x[i]
```

One equation I'm interested in looks like prefix sum, but with a multiplication:

```
y[i] = A*y[i-1] + x[i]
```

Another is having deeper recursion:

```
y[i] = y[i-1] + y[i-2] + x[i]
```

Outside of ways of tackling these two variations, I'm wondering if there are resources that cover how to adapt problems like the above into prefix sum form. Or more generally, techniques for adopting/adapting prefix sum to make it more flexible.

Comment: It's a pretty big subject: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_calculus  What specifically do you want to do with these prefix sums?

Comment: Also, a lot of digital signal processing is concerned with equations like this, so there is much practical knowledge there, too.

Comment: I've only just learned of prefix sum in the context of a tool for parallelising recurrence relations. I was hoping (maybe naively) that there would be a resource with recipes around this idea. Something that could explain to a non-mathematician how to play with a recurrence relation to turn it into something prefix sum-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1)

`y[i] = A*y[i-1] + x[i]`

can be written as

```
y[z] = A^z * y[0] + Sum(A^(z-j) * x[j]) 
    ,where j E [z,1].
```

`A^z * y[0]` can be calculated in `O(log(z))`

`Sum(A^(z-j) * x[j])` can be calculated in `O(z)`.

If the maximum size of the sequence is known beforehand (say `max`), then you can precompute a modified prefix sum array of `x` as

```
prefix_x[i] = A*prefix_x[i-1] + x[i]

     then Sum(A^(z-j) * x[j]) is simply prefix_x[z]
     and the query becomes O(1) with O(max) precomputation.
```

(2)

`y[i] = y[i-1] + y[i-2] + x[i]`

can be written as

```
y[z] = (F[z] * y[1] + F[z-1] * y[0]) + Sum(F[z-j+1] * x[j]) 
    ,where j E [z,2] and F[x] = xth fibonaci number
```

`(F[z] * y[1] + F[z-1] * y[0])` can be calculated in `O(log(z))`

`Sum(F[z-j+1] * x[j])` can be calculated in `O(z)`.

If the maximum size of the sequence is known beforehand (say `max`), then you can precompute a modified prefix sum array of x as

```
prefix_x[i] = prefix_x[i-1] + prefix_x[i-2] + x[i]

     then Sum(F[z-j+1] * x[j]) is simply prefix_x[z]
     and the query becomes O(1) with O(max) precomputation.
```